# A very general complex torus is simple

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let us parametrize the set of lattices inside $\mathbb{C}^g$ with the open dense subset $U = \text{GL}_{2g}(\mathbb{R})$ of $\mathbb{R}^{4g^2}$. Does there exist a countable family $(Z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of algebraic real hypersurfaces of $\mathbb{R}^{4g^2}$ such that for every matrix $M \in U \setminus \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Z_n$, the only complex subtori of $X = \mathbb{C}^g/\Gamma_M$ are $X$ and $\{0\}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think yes. Let $J$ be the complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^{2g}$. Let $L$ be the lattice. Then there is a complex subtorus if and only if $L$ intersects some complex-linear subspace in a full sub-lattice. Thus, there are no complex subtori if and only if for all $x_1,\dots,x_k\in L$ there do not exist $y_1,\dots,y_k\in L$ such that $$\textrm{span}\{x_1,Jx_1,x_2,Jx_2,\dots,x_k,Jx_k\}=\textrm{span}\{x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\dots,x_k,y_k\}.$$ This is countably many real-algebraic conditions.

Comment: Some linear independence conditions probably should be thrown in for good measure. Also, clearly $k<g$ as otherwise we would get the whole space.